# Determining the origin of the more dominant sound produced by two colliding bodies

Tags: waves, acoustics, collision

When two objects collide, such as your hands clapping together, how do you determine if the sound being produced is predominantly coming from the physical collision of the two objects, or from the air being rapidly force out between said objects?

For example, I heard a crocodile handler say that the loud popping sound a crocodile makes when snapping its jaws comes primarily from the air being forced out from between them rather than from the jaws themselves colliding together.

How could you test this claim? How could you distinguish between the sound being produced from the sudden out-rushing air and that of the physical collision?

Answer (score 1):

As for hand clapping, you can perform the following "experiment": study the dependence of the volume depending on the shape of your palms: 1: () - convex outside, 2: )( - convex inside. The sound is louder in the first case. The results of this "experiment" suggest that the sound is mostly caused by air forced out.